# Find sql connected component between many to many entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, graph

I have two basic entities: financial plan and purchase request. Theese two entities are in many-to-many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE FinancialPlan
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PurchaseRequest
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE FP_PR
(
    FP_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FinancialPlan(ID),
    PR_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PurchaseRequest(ID)
);
```

**Problem:** find all requests, related to specified plan, and all plans, related to requests, related to specified plan, ...

Model could be represented as a graph, where each node represents a plan, or a request, and each edge represents a relationship, then the problem could be rephrased as **find connected component, which specified node belongs to**.

Example:

```
Plan     Request    FP_PR

ID  |    ID  |      FP_ID|PR_ID|
----|    ----|      -----|-----|
1   |    1   |      1    |1    |
2   |    2   |      2    |1    |
3   |    3   |      2    |2    |
4   |               3    |2    |
5   |               4    |2    |
                    5    |3    |
```

Find connected component of finplan ID=1

Desired output:

```
FP_ID | PR_ID|
------+------+
1     | 1    |
2     | 1    |
2     | 2    |
3     | 2    |
4     | 2    |
```

I am currently doing it recursively on app side, which may generate to many requests and hang the DB server, could this be done with some recursive DB approach?

Visualization:
[image]
Starting entity is marked by arrow.
Desired output is circled.

Comment: @Alex, read the question please

Comment: I suggest you try to explain it in simpler terms, also you tagged your question with mysql and sql-server tags. Do you have a specific RDBMS in mind?

Comment: @Alex, I have updated my question with visual representation, hope it will clarify things a bit.
As for RDBMS, I must provide sql server solution, though I thougt that mysql solution should be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Server solution**

I guess the main problem is you need to compare by `PR_ID` then `FP_ID`. So in recursive part there must be a `CASE` statement. On 1 run we take data by `FP_ID` on second by `PR_ID` and etc with the help of modulo.

```
DECLARE @fp int = 1

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  f.FP_ID,
            f.PR_ID, 
            1 as lev
    FROM #FP_PR f
    WHERE f.FP_id = @fp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  f.FP_ID,
            f.PR_ID,
            lev+1
    FROM cte c
    CROSS JOIN #FP_PR f -- You can use INNER JOIN instead
    WHERE CASE (lev+1)%2 WHEN 0 THEN f.PR_ID WHEN 1 THEN f.FP_ID END = CASE (lev+1)%2 WHEN 0 THEN c.PR_ID WHEN 1 THEN c.FP_ID END
    AND NOT (f.PR_ID = c.PR_ID AND f.FP_ID = c.FP_ID)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Output:

```
FP_ID   PR_ID   lev
1       1       1
2       1       2
2       2       3
3       2       4
4       2       4
```